# Обратится к полю переменной

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная acc, типа object, у нее следующее содержимое:

```
{
  address: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  Key: '1234567',
  Trans: [Function: Trans],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt]
}
```

Как можно обратиться допусти к полю address и вывести его?

Comment: `console.log(acc.address);`

Answer (score 0):

Можно через точку, как вам подсказали в комментариях:

```
console.log(acc.Key)
```

Можно предварительно деструктурировать, присвоив переменным значения соответствующих ключей:

```
const {address, Key, Trans, sign, encrypt} = acc
console.log(Key)
```

Деструктуризацией удобно принимать входные параметры функции в виде объекта